# Angular KendoGrid RowReorderable, drop doesn't work on newly added rows

Tags: angular, row, kendo-grid

I have a KendoGrid with a datasource, where i've added a rowreorder-column and i've put the rowReorderable=true.

When the grid is loaded i can drag and drop these rows to change the order. But when i've dynamically added some rows i can't drop on these rowindexes. Only on the first 4 rows because they were already there.

Here's a simple stackblitz example where i've replicated the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5b3vsr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The fix for the simulation appeared to be this.gridData = [...this.gridData, ...samplecustomers]

But in my main project this fix doesn't seem to resolve the issue. My code for this project:

```
 openTagSelectionPopup() {
    this.popupService.showEntitySelectionPopup<BaseTag>({
        title: this.translate.get('i18n:LABEL.TAG_SELECTION'),
        entitySet: 'UserBaseTags',
        singleEntitySet: 'BaseTags',
        includes: 'Asset.AssetType,MeasurementUnit.Measurement',
        sort: [{ field: 'Asset.Path', dir: 'asc' }, { field: 'Name', dir: 'asc' }],
        multiSelect: true,
        selectionRequired: false,
        columns: [
            { field: 'Asset.Path', title: this.translate.get('i18n:TAG.ASSET'), filterable: true },
            { field: 'Name', title: this.translate.get('i18n:TAG.NAME'), filterable: true },
            { field: 'MeasurementUnit.Name', title: this.translate.get('i18n:TAG.MEASUREMENT_UNIT'), filterable: true },
            { field: 'MeasurementUnit.Symbol', title: this.translate.get('i18n:TAG.MEASUREMENT_UNIT.SYMBOL'), filterable: true }
        ]
    }).subscribe({
        next: result => {
            if (result && result.length) {
                let addedItems: DataSourceProductionConsumptionItemTag[] = [];
                result.forEach((tag: BaseTag) => {
                    if (findIndex(this.items, (item: DataSourceProductionConsumptionItemTag) => item.TagId == tag.Id) == -1) {
                        addedItems.push({
                            TagId: tag.Id,
                            Tag: tag,
                            Category: '',
                            Color: '#000000'
                        });
                    }
                });
                this.items = [...this.items, ...addedItems];
            }
        }
    });
}

        <kendo-grid #itemsGrid [kendoGridBinding]="items" [height]="410"  style="margin-bottom: 16px;" [rowReorderable]="true"
    kendoGridSelectBy="TagId" [(selectedKeys)]="selectedItemKeys" 
    (cellClick)="cellClick($event)" (cellClose)="cellClose($event)">
        <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
            <button kendoButton look="outline" (click)="openTagSelectionPopup()">{{ 'i18n:DATASOURCE.TAGS.ADD' |
                translate }}</button>
            <button kendoButton look="outline" [disabled]="selectedItemKeys.length === 0"
                (click)="removeItems()">{{ 'i18n:DATASOURCE.TAGS.REMOVE' | translate }}</button>
            <kendo-formerror *ngIf="hasGridErr()">{{gridErr}}</kendo-formerror>
        </ng-template>
        <kendo-grid-rowreorder-column [width]="40"></kendo-grid-rowreorder-column>

        <kendo-grid-column [title]="translate.get('i18n:DATASOURCE.PRODUCTION_CONSUMPTION.TAG')" [field]="'TagId'">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex>
                {{ getTagDescription(dataItem) }}
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

But the UI does seem to be loaded correctly after adding some rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this error is happening because you are pushing the same array multiple times, remember that arrays are stored by reference in JavaScript, so even though we do `[...customers]`, that creates a new reference for the array, but not the array elements, so what I have done is, when you add the same elements again into the list, I create a new reference for each of the elements in the array, this seems to eliminate the bug, when you push new array element each time into the array it will not cause this issue, just for this scenario you have this issue, due to pushing the same array elements multiple times.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GridItem } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { customers, sampleCustomers } from './customers';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <button kendoButton (click)="addCustomers()">Add</button>
        <button kendoButton (click)="removeCustomers()">Remove</button>
            <kendo-grid
                [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
                [rowReorderable]="true"
                [height]="420">
                    <kendo-grid-rowreorder-column [width]="40"></kendo-grid-rowreorder-column>
                    <kendo-grid-column field="CompanyName" [width]="260" title="Company Name"></kendo-grid-column>
                    <kendo-grid-column field="ContactName" [width]="180" title="Contact Name"></kendo-grid-column>
                    <kendo-grid-column field="City" [width]="100"></kendo-grid-column>
                    <kendo-grid-column field="ContactTitle" title="Contact Title"></kendo-grid-column>
            </kendo-grid>
        `,
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
      public gridData: unknown[] = customers;
    
      addCustomers() {
        this.gridData = [
          ...this.gridData,
          ...sampleCustomers.map((x) => ({ ...x })),
        ];
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    
      removeCustomers() {
        this.gridData.splice(4, 9);
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5b3vsr-z4fvaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcustomers.ts)

Comment: I've actually been able to solve it myself in this simulation as well by just using this.gridData = [...this.gridData, ...sampleCustomers] but this fix didn't seem to work in my actual project. I've added necessary information to the main question information.

Comment: @Dylan In your project do a `cloneDeep` from lodash, before pushing anything into the array, it will work fine after that!

Comment: A clonedeep of what? The addeditems are already new. Or do you mean the items theirselves?

Comment: @Dylan Why not try both, one of them might fix your problem!

Comment: I've tried with this: this.items = [...cloneDeep(this.items), ...cloneDeep(addedItems.map((x) => ({...x})))];

The problem still occurs.

Comment: @Dylan please replicate in stackblitz and share back!

Comment: It's resolved, the reason I failed to replicate the problem in StackBlitz is because it used the latest version of Kendo, and in my project I was using v12.0.1. When using this version in StackBlitz the issue was there as well. I'm gonna upgrade the version in my main project and all should be resolved.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5b3vsr?file=package.json

Comment: Indeed, the issue was fixed in v.13.0.3

Comment: @topalkata great! Do update in your question for future reference by others